# How to make a button show fields from separate tables based on combobox data?

Tags: ms-access, button, combobox

I have three combo-boxes and have them responsive to each other, but I don't know how to have a button show only certain fields based on the data selected in the combo-boxes.

I have 5 tables of games that have their statistics in them, and one combo-box for game, one for team, and the last for statistic. Is there a way to have the button show only the data that is selected via combo-box? I was wondering if anyone can help me out. 
Thanks

tparm

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to select value in a combo box, then click a button which will open/run query or form having data matching combo-box value?

Comment: yes, i want the button to find the data in other tables based on the selected values in the combo-boxes.

Comment: Can you put screenshot of table data with heading row?